# How to properly register a basic progressive web app service worker?

Tags: javascript, android, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to register a service worker on my web app, I added on the bottom of my page this script:

```
<script>
// this part is the service worker:
     if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
        // Register service worker
        console.log('Service Worker is supported');
        navigator.serviceWorkerContainer.register('service-worker.js').then(function(reg){
        console.log("Service Worker registration succeeded. Scope is "+reg.scope);
        }).catch(function(err){
            console.error("Service Worker registration failed with error "+err);
        });
    }
</script>
```

and on my server on the same folder I created a file service-worker.js:

```
console.log('Started', self);
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  self.skipWaiting();
  console.log('Installed', event);
});
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
console.log('Activated', event);
});
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('Push message received', event);
});
```

When I inspect it on chrome developer application I click on Service Workers, and nothing shows up.

When I run lighthouse report it gives me an error on Registers a Service Worker.

I am looking for a simple setup to have the download button for my progressive web app, that is actually only a simple web page with a few images and a couple of iframes.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you read through this?: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers

Comment: Without enough info it is difficult to debug. What do you see in the console? Do you see the output from `console.log("Service Worker registration succeeded. Scope is "+reg.scope);`

Answer (score 1):

The following code would register the service worker.

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')
  .then(function(registration) {
    console.log('Registration successful, scope is:', registration.scope);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Service worker registration failed, error:', error);
  });
}
```

Please check [Google's Introduction to Service worker](https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There is very little information to go by here for your problem. There are lot of things that could be wrong. 
But try adding a forward slash to the line below as I think you are missing it -

Before:

`navigator.serviceWorkerContainer.register('service-worker.js')`

After:

`navigator.serviceWorkerContainer.register('/service-worker.js')`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem, I was able to properly setup a very basic service worker using [those files](https://github.com/mozilla/serviceworker-cookbook/tree/master/immediate-claim) from mozilla/serviceworker-cookbook.

I deleted my old code, and uploaded on my server those files [index.js](https://github.com/mozilla/serviceworker-cookbook/blob/master/immediate-claim/index.js) and [service-worker.js](https://github.com/mozilla/serviceworker-cookbook/blob/master/immediate-claim/service-worker.js), and I added `<script src="./index.js"></script>`  to my main page and it worked fine.